# Will steam workshop download mods while playing a game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I am installing a few big mods for skyrim, and I don't want to wait for them to finish. Can I start playing the game and expect them to still be downloaded, so that when I restart the game later on they appear in the data list?

Comment: I think it should, thats why `Allow downloads during gameplay` (in `Settings` under `Downloads` tab) is for, right?

Comment: I thought that would only apply to games and not to workshop items. Am I wrong then?

Comment: Well, for me, the game `Left 4 Dead 2` was downloading items from workshop while I was playing... Don't know if it's same for Skyrim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will download in the background.

The only reasons mods wouldn't download is if you play a game which uses more that a specific bandwidth which steam sets.

Skyrim is an offline game aswell so they should download fine in the background.